# Tuple IndexError when looping through csv file

Tags: python, function, csv, for-loop, arraylist

I have a csv file(see below) that contains speeds and speedlimits. I want to be able to input say 90% and the program to output all the cars that were driving at a speed 90% or more over the speed limit. See goal output below. I am trying to make a new list(data list) with the rows of cars over x% that I then can sort etc.
I currently receive the "IndexError: tuple index out of range" on line 10 for the if statement. I am a novice, can someone explain why I receive this error? Appreciate any help with my code.

Code:

```
import csv

def speedbreach(camera_data):
    percentage = float(input(r"% over speed limit to filter by: "))
    with open(camera_data, 'r', encoding = 'UTF-8') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
        datalist = []
        first_row = next(reader)
        for row in enumerate(reader): 
            if ((row[1]) - (row[2])) / (row[2]) * 100 > percentage:    
                datalist.append(row)           
    return datalist 

camera_data = speedbreach('cameraData.csv')
print(camera_data)
```

Goal output:

```
There were 12 breaches that were more than 90% over the speed limit. 
 
Time       LocationID       Speed Limit            Speed    Date 
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
07:45:29   14039010             70                 135      2021-09-11 
12:06:26   14007040             80                 224      2021-09-11 
12:32:28   14090060             70                 159      2021-09-11 
13:19:09   14090050             70                 145      2021-09-11 
15:05:15   14048010             60                 163      2021-09-11
```

Current output: I input the percentage but then get the IndexError: tuple index out of range

Csv File (cameraData.csv):

```
LocationID;Speed Limit;Speed;Date;Time
14075010;40;55;2021-09-11;11:15:31
14075010;40;54;2021-09-11;08:09:17
14075010;40;53;2021-09-11;13:02:41
14075010;40;49;2021-09-11;13:02:55
14075010;40;47;2021-09-11;13:14:45
```

EDIT: Full Error Traceback

```
% over speed limit to filter by: 90
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 14>()
     11                 datalist.append(row)           
     12     return datalist 
---> 14 camera_data = speedbreach('cameraData.csv')
     15 print(camera_data)

Input In [1], in speedbreach(camera_data)
      8     first_row = next(reader)
      9     for row in enumerate(reader): 
---> 10         if ((row[1]) - (row[2])) / (row[2]) * 100 > percentage:    
     11             datalist.append(row)           
     12 return datalist

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Did you mean: `for row in reader:`?

Comment: enumerate() produces tuples of count , value . You are not using count so do not need enumerate.

Comment: Hi I have updated the question with the full error traceback

Comment: Yes, that's where I thought the error would be. Its because on the previous line you use `enumerate()`. You should remove that as I've already suggested.